# How to find a substring in a line from a text file and add that line or the characters after the searched string into a list using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, search, find

I have a MIB dataset which is around 10k lines. I want to find a certain string (for eg: `"SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID"`) in the text file and add the whole line into a list. I am using Jupyter Notebooks for running the code.

I used the below code to search the search string and it print the searched string along with the next two strings.

```
basic = open('mibdata.txt')
file = basic.read()
city_name = re.search(r"SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID(?:[^a-zA-Z'-]+[a-zA-Z'-]+) {1,2}", file)
city_name = city_name.group()
print(city_name)
```

Sample lines in file:

```
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.10 = OID: NOTIFICATION-LOG-MIB::notificationLogMIB
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.1 = STRING: The MIB for Message Processing and Dispatching.
```

The output expected is

**SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.10 = OID: NOTIFICATION-LOG-MIB::notificationLogMIB**

but i get only

**SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.10 = OID: NOTIFICATION-LOG-MIB**

The problem with changing the number of string after the searched strings is that the number of strings in each line is different and i cannot specify a constant. Instead i want to use '\n' as a delimiter but I could not find one such post.

P.S. Any other solution is also welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDIT***

You can read all lines one by one of the file and look for a certain Regex that matches the case.

`r(NMPv2-MIB::sysORID).*` finds the encounter of the string in the parenthesis and then matches everything followed after.

```py
import re
basic = open('file.txt')
entries = map(lambda x : re.search(r"(SNMPv2-MIB::sys).*",x).group() if re.search(r"(SNMPv2-MIB::sys).*",x) is not None else "", basic.readlines())
non_empty_entries = list(filter(lambda x : x is not "", entries))
print(non_empty_entries)
```

If you are not comfortable with Lambdas, what the above script does is 
taking the text from the file, splits it into lines and checks all lines individually for a regex match.
Entries is a list of all lines where the match was encountered.

**EDIT vol2**
Now when the regex doesn't match it will add an empty string and after we filter them out.

Comment: I used the code that you have mentioned as follows:      

`import re  
basic = open('mibdata.txt')  
entries = list(map(lambda x : re.search(r"(SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID).*",x).group(), basic.readlines()))  
print(entries)`  

I am getting an error saying **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'**
I am using Jupyter Notebook (Python3), does that create a problem?

Comment: Apologies for the poor formatting.  
I tried it in a [regex editor](https://pythex.org) and it worked fine.

Comment: I tried it without the `list(map(lambda()))` . The regex works without the lambda function. I'll see if I can do something with loops.

Comment: @AshutoshP Yeah its failing when there are lines without the match. 

`list(map(lambda x : re.search(r"(SNMPv2-MIB::sys).*",x).group() if re.search(r"(SNMPv2-MIB::sys).*",x) is not None else "", basic.readlines()))`


This will add an empty string every time it doesn't find a match. you can filter the new list for empty string entries after.

Comment: It's working now. Thank you so much. I shall need to understand this. Have not seen this kind of a lambda function, but I think i understand. When there is no match a none is created and when there's match, the data is extracted and the next line is to remove those none elements from the list.